# Telerik RADEditor Failing to render with IIS Url Rewrite

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config, telerik

am using IIS Url Rewrite to create friendly url, i have noticed after enabling it the radeditor fail to render as in the image :https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZo2O.png

The rule am using look like this in web.config :

```
 <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="Default.aspx?name={R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I have changed DialogHandler from aspx to axd and also changed the path for it to look like below and also cant render properly

```
<add path="~/Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I examined the provided screenshot and noticed that the problem is that RadEditor does not load its CSS classes for its toolbar.

Try to register the skin by enabling the [CDN stylesheet](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/stylesheetmanager-cdn-support.html) or manually as shown in this article: [Registering an external skin of RadEditor](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/editor/register-external-skin-vista-radeditor.aspx).